# Как сделать десериализацию JSON?

Tags: c#, json

Есть такой такой класс:

```
public record ComplexUrl
{
    [JsonProperty("api")]
    public string ApiUrl { get; init; } = "";

    [JsonProperty("web")]
    public string? WebUrl { get; init; }
}
```

Нужно десериализировать в него `json`. Однако `json` может быть двух видов:

```
...
"links":
{    
    "self":
    {
        "api": "http://api.freelancehunt.com/v2/projects/299172",
        "web": "http://freelancehunt.com/project/project-with-bids/299172.html"
    },
    "bids": "...",
    "другие ссылки": "другие значения"
}
...
```

и

```
...
"links":
{   
    "self": "http://api.freelancehunt.com/v2/projects/299172",
    "другие ссылки": "другие значения"
}
...
```

Я пытался использовать кастомный конвертер и навесить его на свойство:

```
public abstract class FhDataResponse<T> : FhResponse
    where T : class
{
    // остальной код...

    [JsonProperty("links")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonComplexUrlConverter))]
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ComplexUrl>? Urls { get; init; }
}
```

Но я не знаю как использовать дезериализацию по умолчанию:

```
internal class JsonComplexUrlConverter : JsonConverter<ComplexUrl>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override ComplexUrl? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ComplexUrl? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(string))
            return new() { ApiUrl = reader.Value!.ToString()! };
        else
            return // defalt converter;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ComplexUrl? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129997/discussion-on-question-by-kuzcode----json).

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

- Поменять аттрибут `JsonProperty`
- Доделать конвертер

Класс ответа:

```
public abstract class FhDataResponse<T> : FhResponse
    where T : class
{
    // ...

    [JsonProperty("links", ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonComplexUrlConverter))] // <------
    public ReadOnlyDictionary<string, ComplexUrl>? Urls { get; init; }
}
```

Конвертер:

```
internal class JsonComplexUrlConverter : JsonConverter<ComplexUrl>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override ComplexUrl? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ComplexUrl? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.ValueType == typeof(string))
            return new ComplexUrl() { ApiUrl = reader.Value!.ToString()! };
        else
            return serializer.Deserialize<ComplexUrl>(reader)!;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ComplexUrl? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ветку `else` можно упростить: `return serializer.Deserialize<ComplexUrl>(reader);`. Без промежуточного словаря.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov о, и вправду, а чего-то думал, что это вызовет рекурсию, спасибо!